# Add as a particular role while creating an account in Drupal 7?

Tags: users

In Drupal 7, I have a role named as "blogger". When user goes to blog site and created an account then a role should set by default as "blogger" rather than "authenticated user". How to do this? Any Suggestions please.

Comment: If every user is a _blogger_ then the easiest way I see is not to have it as a separate role at all; instead assign similar permissions to _authenticated_ user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from this Auto Assign Role Module - http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole .

In congifuration settings, We can assign for automatic role.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my comment as answer. If every user is a blogger then the easiest way I see is not to have it as a separate role at all; instead assign similar permissions to authenticated user.

Or you could change the role of the user by implementing [hook_user_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7):

```
function MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $account->role = 'blogger';
  user_save($account, $edit = array(), $category = 'account');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for u r reply. I have another user also in this user table, it is not only one blogger. It is not the matter as for now. 
I kept the code as below two ways in user.module page, but it is not inserting as "blogger" role... what I need to do.

1)
function hook_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  $account->role = 'blogger';
  user_save($account, $edit = array(), $category = 'account');
}


2) 
function hook_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  db_insert('users')->fields(array(
    'role' => 'blogger',
  ))->execute();
}

Comment: It is [**not recommended to hack core**](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core). You should implement the code in a custom module. See [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you need to add the role name - together with its key - into the new user's 'roles' array. In the example below, the role 'teacher' has a rid of 8:-

```
function MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category){
  $account->roles[8]='teacher';
}
```